# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un registro de mi base de datos en mysql después de que cumpla 3 años dentro?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema he estado aprendiendo un poco sobre los `Stored Proccedure` de mysql y  estoy pensando en implementarlos para limpiar un sistema automáticamente, el punto es que no llevo mucho con esto y estoy algo perdido espero que me puedan dar un ejemplo más o menos de como quedaría esa sentencia,

O si algo mas que no se muy bien ¿qué es mejor usar los procedimientos almacenados o triggers? es que mi sistema lo subire a un host ¿habrá problema? :/ De Antemano Gracias!

Comment: Desgraciadamente, tu pregunta parece orientada a basada en opiniones. No creo que tenga una respuesta correcta. Por mi parte te diría, que ninguna de las opciones que planteas, porque no me parece correcto eliminar registros de una base de datos.  Para mejorarla, trata de que tenga una respuesta concreta. mira [ask]

Comment: Umm son dos preguntas y ya me han constestado anteriormente sobre procedimientos almacenados con algunas sentencias de los stored procedure y me han ayudado mucho!! y ademas son registros temporales de usuarios , es un requerimiento de mi sistema.

Comment: ok.. pero los triggers se ejecutan cada vez que le pasa algo a una tabla.. y los SP se tienen que disparar manualmente... entonces??

Comment: Entonces los sp no se pueden quedar activos para que sigan funcionando automaticamente? :/

Comment: Quizás podrías crear un cron job que se ejecute una vez al día y que llame al procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Pero cron jobs es solo para linux y ademas como podria unificarlo en la bd

Comment: Como bien ha dicho @gbianchi, los SP tienen que ser llamados manualmente y los trigger se lanzan cuando ocurre algo en una tabla. Yo tampoco soy partidario de dejar un tarea en segundo plano que borre registros, pero si es una necesidad, lo que necesitas son eventos. [Aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) te dejo la documentación para que le eches un ojillo. Esto en caso de que este utilizando MySQL

Comment: El equivalente a un cron job en Windows sería una [tarea programada](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc721931.aspx). La idea sería la misma: tener un script en PHP que se conecte a la base de datos y ejecute el procedimiento almacenado, y configurar una tarea programada para que corra una vez al día (o las veces que quieras)